# VS Code's Extension "Code Spell Checker" not working for some specific HTML files

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS code, "Code Spell Checker" extension not working for some specific files. For rest files its working fine. The error message is shown in the image attached.[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaT3Q.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you add a minimal example of the "specific files" that do not work? Also, please preferably copy the error message here in a text form to make it more accessible for others.

Comment: it's self explanatory, your word size is too high

Comment: Word Size is not high. It works well for files with even more words size than this file. This file is relatively small comparing to other big files. This extension is working fine for other big files but not for this comparatively small files in word count. That's why it freaks me out